# Scrapy: drop item from scraper

Tags: scrapy

I would like to drop an item from the scraper itself instead of add the particular dropping logic of this scraper into the pipeline due is a specific case.

Scrapy has DropItem exception that is [nicely handled](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/c377c14e3263ce3c2bffa446cd0965006e845664/scrapy/core/scraper.py#L226-L229) from the Pipeline but it produces an error if is raised from the scraper:

```
#...
raise DropItem('Item dropped ' + self.id())
```

Output:

```
2019-11-13 13:27:27 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://domain.tld/> (referer: http://domain.tld/referer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/local/core/core/spiders/my_spider.py", line 46, in parse get.photos())
scrapy.exceptions.DropItem: Item dropped 35
```

Is there a more elegant way to handle this situation?

Comment: By scraper you mean a Spider callback? Spider callbacks cannot _drop_ items, instead they must _not_ yield them in the first place. Raising `DropItem` from outside a pipeline does not really make sense, could you explain the situation that lead to this?

Comment: @Gallaecio what do you mean with "a Spider callback"? the scenario is simple; a scraper getting multiple data from items, if one of them is not desired the scraper should drop the entire item so I need to avoid to yield it. I want to do it following the best approach instead of raising a wild exception.

Comment: In your `Spider` subclass, you are returning or yielding items from one or more methods. In those methods, you could change your code not to return/yield that item which you want to drop.

Comment: I got you, I could change my code to skip yielding but was thinking Scrapy might has a built-in mechanism to handle this so I can see the item has been skipped in the metrics the scraper gives once it finishes. This is possible from the pipeline but not from the scrapper as far as I know.

Comment: You can modify the stats from a spider as well, even create new stats. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html

Comment: Great @Gallaecio. So, sumarising, I think skipping to yield the item plus adding it as skipped in the stats plus logging it _should_ be enough. Thanks!

Comment: in my case I want to make the decision after the headers have been received, so I am raising DropItem in the signal handler
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.headers_received, 
        signal=scrapy.signals.headers_received)